# No output from Reactive Module using selectizeGroup

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to have one pickerinput limit the options in the Selectize Group module of ShinyWisgets. I can get that to work using a reactive expression. However, nothing is produced in the table for me to view the results. What am I missing?

I suspect I made an error in the mpg_filter expression.

```
# https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/reference/selectizeGroup-module.html

library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

data("mpg", package = "ggplot2")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 10, offset = 1,
      tags$h3("Filter data with selectize group"),
      panel(
        pickerInput(
          inputId = "car_select",
          choices = unique(mpg$manufacturer),
          options = list(
            `live-search` = TRUE,
            title = "None selected"
          ),
        ),


        selectizeGroupUI(
          id = "my-filters",
          params = list(
            manufacturer = list(inputId = "manufacturer", title = "Manufacturer:"),
            model = list(inputId = "model", title = "Model:"),
            trans = list(inputId = "trans", title = "Trans:"),
            class = list(inputId = "class", title = "Class:")
          )
        ),
        status = "primary"
      ),
      dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mpg_filter <- reactive({
    mpg %>%
      filter(mpg$manufacturer %in% input$car_select)
  })


  res_mod <- reactive({
    callModule(
      module = selectizeGroupServer,
      id = "my-filters",
      data = mpg_filter(),
      vars = c("manufacturer", "model", "trans", "class")
    )
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable(res_mod())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [v0.5.0](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/blob/81cff437b6c10b7074ae15ddfca1f5c9534a43a8/NEWS.md#shinywidgets-050) [(November 2019)](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/releases/tag/v0.5.0),

> `selectizeGroupServer()` (module `selectizeGroup`) now accept reactive data and reactive vars arguments, see examples for details `?selectizeGroupServer`.

The last example in `?selectizeGroupServer` is effectively a direct answer to this question:

```
# Subset data -------------------------------------------------------------

library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

data("mpg", package = "ggplot2")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 10, offset = 1,
      tags$h3("Filter data with selectize group"),
      panel(
        pickerInput(
          inputId = "car_select",
          choices = unique(mpg$manufacturer),
          options = list(
            `live-search` = TRUE,
            title = "None selected"
          )
        ),
        selectizeGroupUI(
          id = "my-filters",
          params = list(
            manufacturer = list(inputId = "manufacturer", title = "Manufacturer:"),
            model = list(inputId = "model", title = "Model:"),
            trans = list(inputId = "trans", title = "Trans:"),
            class = list(inputId = "class", title = "Class:")
          )
        ),
        status = "primary"
      ),
      DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  mpg_filter <- reactive({
    subset(mpg, manufacturer %in% input$car_select)
  })
  
  res_mod <- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "my-filters",
    data = mpg_filter,
    vars = c("manufacturer", "model", "trans", "class")
  )
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(res_mod())
    res_mod()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Note** `data = mpg_filter` (the reactive itself, not a call to it) in `callModule(module = selectizeGroupServer)`

---

**Outdated answer**

The difficulty stems from the fact that `selectizeGroupServer` does not accept a `reactive` as the `data` argument. If it did, it would be simpler. Here is a workaround:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mpg_filter <- reactive({
    mpg %>%
      filter(mpg$manufacturer %in% input$car_select)
  })
  
  res_mod <- reactive({})
  
  observe({
    res_mod <<- callModule(
      module = selectizeGroupServer,
      id = "my-filters",
      data = mpg_filter(),
      vars = c("manufacturer", "model", "trans", "class")
    )
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable(res_mod())
}
```

Here is another one:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mpg_filter <- reactive({
    mpg %>%
      filter(mpg$manufacturer %in% input$car_select)
  })
  
  
  res_mod <- reactive({
    callModule(
      module = selectizeGroupServer,
      id = "my-filters",
      data = mpg_filter(),
      vars = c("manufacturer", "model", "trans", "class")
    )
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable(res_mod()())
}
```

Note the only change: `res_mod()()`. This is because `res_mod()` itself is a reactive, since `callModule` is wrapped in `reactive` (not just `res_mod` itself, but the resulting call), so we have to call it twice like `res_mod()()`.
This doesn't happen in the first suggestion, but I had to hack a bit with the initialization of `res_mod`, and then `<<-`, to avoid a bug when `res_mod` is called while still undefined.
I would still go with the first, since `res_mod()()` is too far from idiomatic Shiny code.

Comment: Hi Aurèle ! Your answer seem to not be working in 2022 (filters doesn't get updated based on the mpg_filter reactive dataframe.
Any hints ?

Comment: Hi Linda, thanks for the heads-up. Since [v0.5.0](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/blob/81cff437b6c10b7074ae15ddfca1f5c9534a43a8/NEWS.md#shinywidgets-050) *`selectizeGroupServer()` now accept reactive data and reactive vars arguments* . The last example in `?selectizeGroupServer` effectively replaces my answer

Comment: Thanks for the update Aurèle. I was just wondering if you knew why the reactive dataframe was not refreshed in `renderDataTable` when using data from a database with `invalidateLater`  (instead of the `mpg`  dataset) ?

Comment: Can you post a new question with a reproducible example?

Comment: Actually I just found the answer by paying more attention to your udpated post. I was trying to use a call to the reactive dataframe in the CallModule ! Thanks again :)